# Why is string template from readLine not working in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, stringtemplate

**My code:**

```
fun main() { 
    println("What's your name?")
    val name= readLine()
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

**Output:** 
What's your name? 
Abhas 
Hello

**My question is:** Why $name is not getting printed? After taking input ' Abhas ' it doesn't show anything and then after I pressed Enter and it prints ' Hello ' only.

Comment: Please include details about how you are starting your application. It's probably because the input is not reaching the app.

Comment: Can you give some details on how you're running this?  (There's nothing wrong with the code itself; I just tried it myself inside IntelliJ, and it printed my name as expected.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you - it is reading some input or it wouldn't get to the `println` statement, and it is printing the value of `name` (which has a value, otherwise it would say *null*).

At a guess, it's something to do with the way you're providing input, where the first line it reads is empty, so you get an empty string (""). You said your output is like this:

```
What's your name?
Abhas
Hello
```

Are you hitting enter/return to get to the next line before you type *Abhas*? That does nothing in the REPL I'm using, but it might count as an (empty) input line in your console